# Calculate coordinates of polygon's points after changing lenght of one side

Tags: vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, polygons

I have a list of points (vectors) on the surface, together they form a polygon. Two sides lead from each point, each side has only two points, these sides form the polygon.

And my problem is: How to calculate the new coordinates of all points, if I wanted to enlarge or shorten one side of the polygon to a given length so that all other side lengths remained the same, only the inner angles of the polygon and the selected side would change.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:** Moved line should be parallel to past self, because previous version of this question had infinite number of solutions, so this version should have only zero or one solution.

Again thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? Please consider showing your efforts. :-)

Comment: Can you change all angles in the polygon?

Comment: Yes, that's not problem, but I'd like to change only two nearest to edge.

Comment: The issue is that the problem is not well defined. Let's take a square $ABCD$ of side $1$, and just change $AB$ to $1.2$. You can make a trapeze $ABCD$, but that's not the only way. You keep $A$ and $C$ fixed, but when you move $B$ you will need to move $C$ as well. That means you change 3 angles. But you can keep $B$ and $D$ fixed (different solution). Maybe it's easier if I explain the other way: say after the change you have a polygon with all sides $1$. Is it a square or parallelogram? And for the last one, what's the angle between sides?

Comment: @Andrei I don't understand question "What's the angle between sides?", angles doesn't need to be same, but can be, angles can be bigger than 180 degrees, and in polygon sides can intersect each other. It just can be any polygon. Let's say I have Hexagon ABCDEF, I want to change length of "AB", I think the best option is to change angles C, F and leave D, E same.

Comment: For example, if after change I have a quadrilateral with all sides 1, the answer is a rhombus. The angles are $\alpha,180-\alpha,\alpha,180-\alpha$. But $\alpha$ can be any number between $0$ and $180$. If it's 90, you have a square. How do you choose $\alpha$?

Comment: I'd try to change nearest angles to side by same angle.

Comment: Probably the best would be that moved line would be parallel to past self.

Comment: I suspect that whatever it is you are trying to do, you are going about it the wrong way. The problem as you have stated it is ill-defined and messy. What is it that you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am making app in Unity3D, where you work with polygons and one function would be to change length of side of polygon, without changing other sides, and I can't find a way to do so.